# Error in minecraft plugin development: Is it up to date? IllegalStateException: Initial initialization

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I am developing a Minecraft plugin of my own and running into a problem every time I try to run the code.

What im making out of the code is that it's telling me something might not be up to date and that the problem is coming from Initialization.

Can you please help me fix this?

```
    [15:13:55 INFO]: [GuiPlus] Enabling GuiPlus v1.0-SNAPSHOT
[15:13:55 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling GuiPlus v1.0-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:203) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:52) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at yarktheshark.guiplus.GuiPlus.<init>(GuiPlus.java:6) ~[?:?]
        at yarktheshark.guiplus.GuiPlus.onEnable(GuiPlus.java:11) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:380) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:483) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:501) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:415) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:468) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:237) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:939) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.lambda$a$0(MinecraftServer.java:177) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
***Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Initial initialization***
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.initialize(PluginClassLoader.java:206) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.<init>(JavaPlugin.java:52) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at yarktheshark.guiplus.GuiPlus.<init>(GuiPlus.java:6) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.<init>(PluginClassLoader.java:80) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:137) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:397) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:305) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:389) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:204) ~[patched_1.16.3.jar:git-Paper-204]
        ... 3 more
[15:13:55 INFO]: [GuiPlus] Disabling GuiPlus v1.0-SNAPSHOT
[15:13:55 INFO]: [GuiPlus]  Plugin Is Disabled!
[15:13:55 INFO]: Running delayed init tasks
[15:13:55 INFO]: Done (4.124s)! For help, type "help"
[15:13:55 INFO]: Timings Reset
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you're trying to initialize or enable a plugin that is already enabled. If you have any plugin that enables/disables other plugins manually (Such as PlugMan) try to disable it. Another reason could be that you're extending the class JavaPlugin multiple times. Remember that JavaPlugin should only be extended in your main class.